# DBA.SE's hot question advertisement doesn't meet guidelines

Tags: bug, design, advertising

(This is a SE design issue - not DBA.SE's community issue - they've got no control over this)

One bit of the community advertisement guidelines reads:

> - **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border surrounding it.**

No, I didn't add that emphasis - it's there in the [original](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2416/450).

This is to make sure there is no misunderstanding about where the advertisement ends and where it begins and what text belongs with what.

On [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), the DBA.SE hot question page looks like:

> [image]

Compare this to others... such as SharePoint's hot question advert:

> [image]

Or Electrical Engineering...

> [image]

Oops... wait a moment... that one is problematic too.

And so is Mathematica:

> [image]

Could these advertisements be brought into line with the guidelines so that they look something more like:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion. We gonna take closer look at border around some ads and also at guidelines as well.

Comment: @Paweł Code Review also lacks the border. http://i.stack.imgur.com/sBhF2.png

Comment: Hey, we have updated low-contrast ads by adding some some border around them. They should be visible on SE network in up to couple days (cache).

Comment: @Paweł those appear to be good, though I'll point out that the recently created one for ELL.SE once again has a background that is white or mostly white and lacks a border around the image.